# asp:Login EnableClientScript

Tags: asp.net, login-control, client-side-validation

We are using ASP.NET 2.0 to build a website, and are using Forms Authentication. As usual I'm using the ASP.NET Login control.

In this project, we are not allowed to use client side (JS) validation, so I want to disable this. Unfortunatly, there doesn't seem to be a EnableClientScript property available like on the various ASP.NET Validator controls.

Does anyone know a way of using the Login control without client side validation scripting so I can avoid creating my own login control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the ASP.NET membership controls are not very configurable, so you would have to implement your own (easy to do), and use the Membership object to handle validating users, and FormsAuthentication to handle other forms related tasks (such as logging out, saving the user's credentials in a ticket, etc).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use the Login control without the built-in client side validation.  But, it is very easy to create your own custom login control so I would just go that route.  Check on the [MSDN site for an example on how to create a custom login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login(VS.80).aspx).